# Autofocus not working when using onMouseDown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two almost identical components that make the focus for the input when it appears:

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-knuth-7smon5?file=/src/index.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-resonance-66lr8n?file=/src/index.js

In the second case, I use the onMouseDown event instead of onClick for the button that triggers the input. In both cases, the input appears, but in the second case, the focus does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the reason why this is happening is because the `click` event is fired after the `mousedown` event therefore the focus is being moved almost instantly after to the button that was clicked.

I'm unsure of your exact use-case but one of the things you can do is use `e.preventDefault()` if you really want to use `onMouseDown`

```
<button
 onMouseDown={(e) => {
   setSearchIsOpen(true);
   e.preventDefault();
 }}
>
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event